# How to send different files depending on what app we chose in the share menu?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, share, provider

I have a problem. I need to create a service that send an mp3 file that synthetize voice from a string sended by an activity, or a mp4 file. I'm able to create the mp3 file and the mp4 file. I also know how to set one of them in the share menu.

My problem is that I want to see every apps which can handle mp3 AND mp4 files and then send the right file to the app selected.

here's my code :

```java
public void setShareContent(MenuItem item, ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider) {
        this.setActionMenu(item,mShareActionProvider);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sounds/hello.mp3");

        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        mIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(mIntent);
    }

    private void setActionMenu(MenuItem item, ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider) {
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    }
```

And my listener from my activity :

```java
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = text.getText().toString();
                myHashReader = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashReader.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, message);

                String exStroragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                File tmpPath = new File(exStroragePath + "/sounds/");
                tmpPath.mkdirs();

                String tmpFileName = "hello.mp3";

                tmpDestFile = tmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + tmpFileName;
                new MySpeech(MyActivity.this, message, tmpDestFile);
                myService.setShareContent(item, mShareActionProvider);
            }
        });
```

I'm blocked from days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creat a chooser something like this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
            intent.setType("mp3/*");

            Intent musicIntent = new Intent(android.provider....);

            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, musicIntent);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select from:");

            Intent[] intentArray = { musicIntent };
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_PIC);
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for but I don't understand the line : Intent musicIntent = new Intent(android.provider....);

What would I put in that constructor ? 

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the provider for music provider is ... :) try ctrl+space to see if there is any suggestions for images it is android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Answer (score 1):

It finally works ! Your code has helped me a lot, but I didn't do what you told me to do, here's my code :

```
public void setShareContent(MenuItem item, ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider) {
                    this.setActionMenu(item,mShareActionProvider);
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sounds/hello.mp3");

                    mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                    mIntent.setType("audio/mp3");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    intent.setType("mp3/*");

                    Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select from : ");
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mIntent);

                    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(chooser);
                }

                private void setActionMenu(MenuItem item, ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider) {
                    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
                }
```